# CreateProcess Error Code 18

Tags: createprocess

Error Code 18 after `CreateProcess`. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;   
    PROCESS_INFORMATION  pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si)); // macro fills a block of memory with zeros
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi)); 
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    BOOL create_proc = CreateProcess(L"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    //printf("Error (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    if(!create_proc)
         printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

    //check
    printf("Error (%d)\n", GetLastError());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's any consolation... the code does not error for me.  Could it be permissions, disk space, or some other reason?

Answer (score 0):

From here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

The seems your error code corresponds to,

ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES
18 (0x12)
There are no more files.

It could be permissions.